# OpenFileDialog does not show complete filename in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, openfiledialog

OpenFileDialog does not show complete filename in Windows 7. The problem is also reported [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525070/openfiledialog-show-part-of-file-name-in-win7).

There is also a work around by setting `openFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false`. But that causes old xp style dialog. Is there any way to fix it without doing the above workaround. There is no window handle in the dialog so i cannot figure out how to add custom window message handler to do sendmessage() to fix it.

```
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
            openFileDialog.FileName = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the other workaround on the connect page?

Answer (score 0):

On the [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525070/openfiledialog-show-part-of-file-name-in-win7#) there is another workaround listed as:

> Posted by Robert Breitenhofer on 10/09/2010 at 01:52 Add:
>
> openFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;
>
> before calling ShowDialog().

I only have Win XP so I cannot test this, hope this helps.

Comment: Both workarounds does same thing. They show xp style dialog on win 7.